# How would use a get() method to access an element in an arrayList?

Tags: java

This is my code I have so far but I don't know how to access an element in the Array myList?

And is the inex of an array list start at 0 or 1?
I have just found out about array lists and i need a few pointers and some help

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

        myList.add("hello");
        myList.add("5");
        myList.add("3");
        myList.add("8");
        int totalElements = myList.size();
        System.out.println(totalElements);

private String[] myList;
    public String getList() {
        return this.myList[0];
```

Comment: You should be able to answer this by just doing a simple Google search.  Please don't ask us to teach you how to use `ArrayList`; there are many good tutorials out there that can help you learn how to use it.

Comment: Agreed, and voted to close. On topic questions should show some degree of research by the question-asker. Questions that can be answered with a quick Google search are off-topic. Here is a link to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Now how would you print out every element in the array list with a for loop?

Comment: @user1254044 - I suggest you take the time to read Oracle's Java tutorial.  Then you won't need to ask such basic questions.

Answer (score 11):

All you have to do is:

```
myList.get(Index);
```

This would return you the type of `Object` you used while creating the `ArrayList`. In your case it will return a `String`. Hence, what you can do is:

```
String firstElement = myList.get(0); //This would return "Hello"
```

This also shows that `ArrayList` indices start with 0

Answer (score 4):

```
String a = myList.get(0); //a = "hello"
String b = myList.get(1); //b = "5"
```

Answer (score 2):

In java, array's index is start from 0.

To access the nth element in one list, you can call `list.get(n)`.